# Unable to build Kernel

Tags: rust, operating-system, kernel

I was following the tutorial of Phillip Opperman (https://os.phil-opp.com/) and I was in the chapter- building the kernel(https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#building-our-kernel) and I keep getting the same error. It seems system-related but I don't know.

```
C:\Users\radri\%radri%\projects\jcomp>cargo build --target jcomp.json
Compiling core v0.0.0 (C:\Users\radri\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core)
Compiling rustc-std-workspace-core v1.99.0 (C:\Users\radri\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\rustc-std-workspace-core)
Compiling compiler_builtins v0.1.71

error: failed to build archive: no such file or directory

error: could not compile `rustc-std-workspace-core` due to previous error

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

error: could not compile `core` due to previous error

error: could not compile `compiler_builtins` due to previous error
```

Comment: The `%radri%` in your working directory looks weird.

Comment: See also [Unable to build any dependencies due to "failed to build archive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181389/unable-to-build-any-dependencies-due-to-failed-to-build-archive) (no answers there, but a few comments)

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot @SvenMarnach I'll look into it.  The working directory thingy asked me to keep it like that according to the rust tutorial so thats why its there.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. I created a new directory without the '%' and its executing properly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a directory without the '%' as apparently Rust "doesn't like" such directory names. Thanks @SvenMarnach

Comment: If @SvenMarnach's comment helped you, you can select this answer as "the" accepted answer to your question!

Comment: How may I go about doing that @AndrewBrown. Sorry for disturbing you over such a small doubt

Comment: Sorry, I could have included a link. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :
"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."